# Link XSL and XML?`

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

how do I link the [xml](http://pastebin.com/Bj6b8FdK) and [xsl](http://pastebin.com/fUEbnvbw) files that I created such that when I open the xml file it automatically applies the stylesheet and displays the required html output for the xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the [stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/) directive.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test2.xsl"?>
```

Comment: It should be `xml-stylesheet`, not `xml:stylesheet`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/

Comment: @MartinHonnen oops - fixed